# How to make a for loop for addition of value from previous iteration into current iteration?

Tags: matlab

I want to put this vector in a LOOP. I don’t know how!

```
y=[a ...
   a + b ...
   a + b + c ...
   a + b + c + b ...
   a + b + c + b + c ...
   a + b + c + b + c + b ...
   a + b + c + b + c + b + c];
```

where , 
a,b,c are all predefined values.
I want this loop to run for ‘n’ number of times.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to construct such a vector in a loop, try the following:

```
v = zeros(n, 1);
for i=1:n
    if (i==1)
        v(i) = a;
    elseif (mod(i,2)==0)
        v(i) = v(i-1)+b;
    else
        v(i) = v(i-1)+c;
    end
end
```

Alternatively, without using loop, as follows:

```
v=[a,repmat([b,c],[1,(n-1)/2])];
v=cumsum(v)';
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop. To get the element which is added on each iteration, use:

```
n=30 %size
v=[a,repmat([b,c],[1,(n-1)/2])];
```

Then use the cumulative sum:

```
v=cumsum(v);
```